# Get an item from a list with (x,y) coords

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `matrix[2][2]` what I stored in a list:

```
var list= ["a","b","c","d"];
```

and I have two coordinates:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
```

I would like to get the `(x,y)` element from the list, for instance: `(x,y)==(0,1)` which is the `c` element.

How can I do that?

*Imaginary matrix* looks like:

```
a b
c d
```

Comment: just do `list[x*2 + y]`

Comment: Shouldn't `(0, 1)` be `"c"`? `(0, 1)` meaning the first item `x = 0` of the second row `y = 1`, right?

Comment: Why not keeping the matrix in a bi-dimensional array (`[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]`) and accessing it exactly as you described (`arr[x][y]`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for that is:

```
index = y * numberOfColumns + x;
```

Where `y` is the row index and `x` is the column index.

So in your case (the number of columns is `2`), it should be:

```
let item = list[y * 2 + x];
```

**Note:** In my example, `x` denotes the column and `y` denotes the row, which I think is the more accurate nomenclature. If you have the opposite (`x` is the row and `y` is the column), then simply switch `x` and `y` in the formula.

**Demo:**

```js
const list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];


let x, y;

x = 0; y = 0;
console.log("(" + x + ", " + y + ") = " + list[y * 2 + x]);

x = 1; y = 0;
console.log("(" + x + ", " + y + ") = " + list[y * 2 + x]);

x = 0; y = 1;
console.log("(" + x + ", " + y + ") = " + list[y * 2 + x]);

x = 1; y = 1;
console.log("(" + x + ", " + y + ") = " + list[y * 2 + x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function list_xy(my_list, x, y)
{
    var c = []  
    c.push(my_list.slice(0,2),my_list.slice(2,4))
    return c[x][y];
}
```